# Does similarity based algorithms outperform SVM/Tree algorithms in text classification ?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, text-classification, cosine-similarity

What performs better for text classification similarity (cosine distance) based algorithms or regular classification methods like SVM or decision trees in terms accuracy and performance? 
Does SVM resolves in finite time with 4GB-8GB RAM systems, while training with large text data ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, you may consider the "No free lunch" theory, [1]. If you have no assumption about the data, then you can not prefer one method over the other. So, you may try different methods and use K-fold to estimate the error measure for each approach. Then, perform appropriate statistical tests to see if the results are statistically different or not.

I hope this helps.

References:

[1] D. H. Wolpert and W. G. Macready, “No free lunch theorems for
optimization,” IEEE Trans. Evol. Comput., vol. 1, pp. 67–82, Apr. 1997